# Bind Multibinding Textbox in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have 3 TextBoxes bind with my class(***Transaction***) properties like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Transaction.Bills100,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="bills100" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="7"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Transaction.Bill50,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="bills50" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="7"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Transaction.Bill20,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="bills20" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="7"></TextBox>
```

Also I have another TextBox where I have done multibinding and done addition of the first three Textboxes like

```
 <TextBox Grid.Column="2" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="7" Name="TotalBills">
   <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{ikriv:MathConverter}" ConverterParameter="x+y+z" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="bills100" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="bills50" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="bills20" />
         </MultiBinding>
     </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```

I want to bind this multibinding textbox with my class(***Transaction***) with property as Transaction.Total like my first three textboxes but it shows error

> Property text is set more than once

Comment: *it shows error*... care to share the details of that error?

Comment: You don't need a binding to set your Total property, you have the three properties in ViewModel:  Bills100, Bills50, Bills20, just update the Total when one of these changes.

Comment: @NovitchiS:I have shown 3 properties, but I have taken 12 properties.But my need is:
I want to bind Total by using my multibinding and on its notify I want to do some other calculation.

Comment: @Sheridan:The error I am getting is 'Property text is set more than once'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we cannot get the value of a two-way binding from one property and then set the value of another property.
Finally I came with a solution like this
 In my Class Transaction

```
private double _totalBills; 
public double TotalBills
{
    get { return _totalBills; }
    set { _totalBills= value; Notify("TotalBills"); }
}
```

In XAML(Instead of Multibinding)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Transaction.TotalBills,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="2" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="7" Name="TotalBills"/>
```

My ViewModel

```
 public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Transaction _transactionDetails;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Transaction= new Transaction();
       _transactionDetails.PropertyChanged += _transactionDetails_PropertyChanged;
    }
    private void _transactionDetails_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "TotalBills":
                _calculate(); //My method for calculation
                break;
        }
    }
}
```